# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException thrown while going through arraylist

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

```
        if (IOThread.getInstance().clientsToAdd.size() > 0) {
            for (Client client : IOThread.getInstance().clientsToAdd) {
                clients.add(client);
                IOThread.getInstance().removeAddedClient(client);
            }
        }
```

When this runs in my main loop I get this error thrown:

```
    [DEBUG]: Added new connection: 79.142.74.45
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at Server.run(Server.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

This method throws the error:

```
    public void removeClient(Client client) {
    Iterator<Client> clientIterator = clients.iterator();
    while (clientIterator.hasNext()) {
        Client currentClient = clientIterator.next();
        if (client.equals(currentClient)) {
            clientIterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line causes the error:

```
IOThread.getInstance().removeAddedClient(client);
```

You are removing client while looping through it.
Use `iterator.remove()` instead.